# Admin "manage categories" error after remove "size chart"extension

Tags: category, error

i'm still having problem. please help!

I recently installed "size chart" extension and removed, and after that,

in my admin page, "Manage Categories" is not working.  But all other page seems to work fine.

I research other peoples question, but still couldn't figured it out.

i'm getting this error below.

Source model "maattabel/categorie" not found for attribute "maattabel_categorie"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get this error because you had an extension that was disabled (like) but a category attribute remained in the database.
If you disabled the extension it means you don't need the attribute anymore. So you can delete it.

Run this query on your database:

```
DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `source_model` = 'maattabel/categorie';
```

Just to be on the safe side, you should look for other attributes that might have a source model that refers to the extension.
Run this query:

```
 SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` where `source_model` like `%maattabel%`.
```

In case you find other records, back-up your db and delete them also.

Answer (score 2):

You should find in table eav_attribute an entry with source_model = 'maattabel/categorie' and set source_model empty. For example, run this query:

UPDATE eav_attribute SET source_model = '' WHERE source_model = 'maattabel/categorie'

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE source_model LIKE "maattabel_%
Then select this row and delete from database
clear cache it has done